# Sublime Text 2 - remove rows where duplicated words are in a list

Tags: sublimetext2

What can I do to delete all line in which one word (and not number) is the same. Here is the example:

```
4,5876746600174000,dog 
4,5876736392287000,nacho 
4,5876692287755000,dog 
4,5876684072439000,tree
4,5876692287773600,dog
4,5876692879655000,dog 
4,5876692434755000,frog
```

I would like to let it automatically delete every line that says "dog" after it was mentioned already once, including all content... any idea? It obviously is a csv file, so maybe its quicker with open office?

Answer (score 0):

To ommit repeated lines for 3rd field you can use:

```
sort -t, -k3 file.csv|sort -t, -k3 -u
```

which will give you:

```
4,5876692287755000,dog
4,5876692434755000,frog
4,5876736392287000,nacho
4,5876684072439000,tree
```

Do NOT try to make it shorter with just one `sort`, as `sort -t, -k3 -u file.csv` will give you different results:

```
4,5876746600174000,dog
4,5876692434755000,frog
4,5876736392287000,nacho
4,5876684072439000,tree
```

Note second field for `dog`'s line has different value (it ommits all lines except the last one for `dog`)

I think it should be good as well to import that CSV file to some database (sqlite?). Than you can make `SELECT` with `GROUP BY`.